# Running multiple forms(2 apps) in my django project

Tags: django, forms

I am having some problems trying to set up another "form-app" to my django project. I have an app called "signups", which works fine and gets the user's contact information. Now I have started another app and have new directory for it called "joins", which is an email list for my users.

For some reason, I can't get the email-app "joins" to run the form properly when I try to test it with "form.as_p". Admin stuff works fine and I can see both "signups" and "joins" in there and both work just fine in admin.

Can I just put all join-app's stuff(views, models, forms) under the signups-app and it should work or am I missing something here which prevents the form of joins-app working?

EDIT:

So the signups-app is the "core-app", which is on the main-page and I'm trying to setupt the joins-formon the main-page too.

Forms (joins): http://gyazo.com/f1083b6be0b40a8267538eb9269ed006

Views (signups): http://gyazo.com/532307f7d2f9e6018cfd31f7cad90d2e

Comment: Need more information. Folder structure, is it in installed apps?, started it using startapp?. A quick snapshot of your forms.py files would help too.

Comment: And the view and template, too.

Comment: Cheers guys, I provided some more information. Here is also
urls: http://gyazo.com/b18108b1439c1cb6566ebc3a0c8f72e2

Comment: And yes I have added it in the installed apps and used manage.py startapp. I think the problem I have hard time understanding is how to setup it beside the "signups"-app as it is the core-app of the whole project.